# SQL Azure Merge Replication

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, merge-replication

Does anyone know if SQL Azure supports merge replication?  I am currently working with the web version of SQL 2008 R2 and it does not support the publication side of replication and I need a solution that will that doesn't cost $7000.

Comment: After looking through a bunch of vague product description pages, I finally called Microsoft and after being transferred 4 times talked to someone who put a ticket in for me... Hopefully someone will be able to answer my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SQL Azure Database does not provide replication currently.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394115.aspx

However, there is the [SQL Azure Data Sync service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data) (currently in preview).

Comment: Thanks David. I totally missed the limitations section. The data sync service sounds great, I guess its worth a try for $10/mo.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: @csetzkorn No more the case, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt589530.aspx
But there is still a significant limitation, only one-way (push) replication is allowed

Answer (score 2):

and if the Sql Azure Data Sync Service doesnt meet your needs, you can always write your own...

see: [Walkthrough of Windows Azure Sync Service Sample](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/walkthrough-of-windows-azure-sync-service-sample.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidPallman points out, there's no replication today (aside from Sync Services).

In addition to the MSDN article he points to, there's a [TechNet article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/996.compare-sql-server-with-sql-azure.aspx) comparing SQL Azure to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked some years ago, but for people that would be asking a similar question, it seems that transactional replication to Azure SQL DB is available (public preview) since November 2015.
Source: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/transactional-replication-to-azure-sql-db/
Regards.